# What is TSR's Warhawks Comic-Modules issue number count

Tags: comics

In the '90s, TSR produced several comic books. Many of these were based on some of the RPG settings TSR produced. The Comic-Module format often included either RPG stats for characters appearing in the comic, sometimes included campaign setting information for running the comic's setting, or sometimes the extra material was a miniature game.

*Warhawks* was a science fiction time travel setting for [Top Secret/S.I](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_Secret_%28role-playing_game%29#Top_Secret.2FS.I._edition). that was exclusively presented through the comic-modules. It seems the run lasted for nine issues. 1-4 titled simply *Warhawks* parts 1 through 4 (of 4). Issues 5 and 6 were titled *Warhawks 2050*. And Issues 7 through 9 were titled *Warhawks Battle of Britain* parts 1 through 3 (of 3).

It appears that there might have been at least two more issues. There is an entry on [Amazon.com for an issue 11](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/555334610X) called Warhawks/Timehawks. Where can I find out more about those issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some hunting around, I've concluded that what you're looking at is actually an artefact of the way in which ISBN numbers are assigned. The comic apparently enjoyed a run of nine issues under the title "**Warhawks**". The following year, the publishers also registered the same comics under a secondary title ("***Warhawks/Timehawks***") which is why the titles actually seem to run up to [#18](https://openlibrary.org/books/OL12120289M/Warhawks_Timehawks_Comic_Modules_%28Tsr_Comic_Modules_No_18%29) on some websites.

Without speaking to the publisher, there's no way to know why they did this (probably some legal mumbo-jumbo involving foreign editions) but I'm quite confident that all of the [ISBN numbers](http://www.bookdepository.co.uk/Warhawks-Timehawks-10-TSR-Inc/9785553345976?b=-3&t=-26#Bibliographicdata-26) seem to lead back to the same set of nine original comics and that there was never a #10 edition.

A pretty solid list of TSR comics can be found [here](http://www.mycomicshop.com/search?pl=TSR)